# Yii2 check if url points to a valid image

Tags: php, yii2

I've just started learning Yii2.
I have a form where user has to input a url to the external image.
Is there some rule/validation that can check if this url exists?
standard [['image'], 'image'], and [['image'], 'url'], are not doing what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the model rules I added

```
[['image'], 'validateImage']
```

Where validateImage is a custom function that I wrote in the same model:

```
    // function that checks if path leads to an actual image
    public function validateImage($attribute, $params, $validator) {
      if (!($something = @getimagesize($this->$attribute))) {
         $this->addError($attribute, 'Such an image doen\'t exist');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own validation like this:

```
['image', function($attribute, $params) {
    if (filter_var($this->image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
        $this->addError('image', 'Not an URL.');
        return;
    }
    try {
        $headers = get_headers($this->image);
        if (!stripos($headers[0], "200 OK"))
            $this->addError('image', 'Invalid URL.');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->addError('image', 'Invalid URL.');
    }
} ],
```

However, on my machine this is a bit slow. But give it a try.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, I've already found solution. I've created a custom function and put it as a filter in rules.

Comment: @Dmitriy Fine. You may want to post your solution by answering your own question. May help others too and it would be interesting. If it is not too special...

Answer (score 0):

you can write custom validation rule in model in rules array you can put below code

```
['image', 'validateimagecheck'],
```

you can `validateimagecheck` fucntion in model like below

```
public function validateimagecheck($attribute, $params)
{
if (!(file_exists($this->image))) {
$this->addError('image', 'Please enter valid image url');
}


}
```